# Fail to start apache2 and mysql server on startup

Tags: server, apache2, mysql

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
On every boot mysql-server and apache2 fail  to start and when i try to start manually  it breaks  and shows following error:

[image]

[image]

After re-installation it works but again in next boot same issue repeated.
During re-installation of apache2:

```
insserv: warning: script 'K01chilli' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'chilli' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'K01chilli' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'chilli' missing LSB tags and overrides
```

is shown and for mysql-server:

```
insserv: warning: script 'K01chilli' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'chilli' missing LSB tags and overrides
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are just warning because you are supposed to add more info, if you want to avoid them you should add this in your init.d script:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          scriptname
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
```

you can get more information there: https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts